# Show drawing conditionally in laravel-excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, maatwebsite-excel

I have an Export which looks like this:

```
class CatalogExport implements WithHeadings, WithDrawings, WithMapping, FromCollection
```

and I want the Drawing to be shown conditionally, but I don't really know how to do it.

I tried it this way:

```
public function drawings()
    {
        $drawing = new Drawing();
        if($this->semnat === 1)
        {
        $drawing->setName('Semnatura');
        $drawing->setDescription('This is my logo');
        $drawing->setHeight(100);
        $drawing->setCoordinates('F3');
        $drawing->setPath(null);
        $drawing->setPath(storage_path('app/public/' . $this->imgPath));
        }

        return $drawing;
    }
```

For any other value than 1 the fields will remain not completed, so I thought there might be no drawing shown. But then I get this error:

```
File not found!
```

So, is there any way to show this drawing conditionally, other than creating two export classes, one which implements WithDrawings and one which doesn't? (but would create a lot of duplicate code)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's some code missing from your question.

Regardless, I'd rejig your drawing function to be like this:

```php
public function drawings()
{
    if($this->semnat === 1 && $this->imgPath)
    {
        $drawing = new Drawing();
        $drawing->setName('Semnatura');
        $drawing->setDescription('This is my logo');
        $drawing->setHeight(100);
        $drawing->setCoordinates('F3');
        $drawing->setPath(null);
        $drawing->setPath(storage_path('app/public/' . $this->imgPath));
        return $drawing;
    }

    return null;
}
```

This code checks to see if `imgPath` is set, and also returns null if `semnat` isn't 1 or `imgPath` is not set.

Comment: Then I get: Call to a member function setWorksheet() on null

Comment: Then there's definitely code missing from your question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Its to late but the solution is:

```
return []
```

for example:

```
public function drawings(){
      $drawings = [];

      if($logo == null)
         return [];
         
      $img_file = $logo;

      
      $drawing = new Drawing();
      $drawing->setName('image');
      $drawing->setDescription('image');
      $drawing->setPath($img_file);
      $drawing->setHeight(70);
      $drawing->setWidth(125);
      $drawing->setOffsetX(5);
      $drawing->setOffsetY(5);
      $drawing->setCoordinates('A1');
      $drawings[] = $drawing;
      
      return $drawings;
   }
```